# How do I keyframe a rig's scale?

Tags: animation, rigging

If I select all bones from a character and hit S for scale and reduce it in size. If I want that to be an animation how do I keyframe that scaling?

Comment: By inserting some keyframes, the same as any other animation. Are you just asking how to animate? or is there some specific problem with what you tried?

Comment: @sambler I know how to animate but I'm kinda new to it. I realize now that I can use the autokeyframe and it is root that get a keyframe but where is this root? How do I scale do that without autokeydrame or are there some thing that only in auto mode that that can add key?

Comment: The root bone is normally the base of the rig, if you have trouble finding the root bone try *Select->Select Pattern* or use the outliner, which also has a search in the header. Once you position a bone, press `I` and choose, say, LocRotScale to keyframe it there, the only thing the autokeyframe does is press `I` for you after you move something. Just remember to change frame before moving anything, not changing the frame before you position an item is the easiest mistake to make - it will replace the current keyframe. For an armature you want to keyframe it in pose mode, not object mode.

Comment: You can set child bones to inherit the scale from the parent bones (I think this is the default, along with rotation). Then you just animate scaling the root bone, and everything else should follow.